# Autocomplete on react code when use class component in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using functional component for long time, which is great on vscode, because it will suggest the props, for example:

I have component A:

```
export default function A({propsA, propsB}){

}
```

Then i use in function B:

```
export default function B() {
  return <A p />;
}
```

It will have suggestion like this

[image]

But when i use class, like:

```
export default class A extends React.Component {}
```

It do not return anything! so it hard to debug and easy to write wrong props

So how can we do that the same way with function in javascript

Note: No typescript, this is an outsource, so i can't use that

Comment: It is impossible without a type script. The reason is that the type is unpredictable.

Comment: So sad :( , react need to complete remove class component in the future